# Can't login to Firebase with CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a weird problem with log in to Firebase using CLI. It's never happened before, so It's weird. I can log in using console.firebase.google.com, but not with CLI.

Because of that, I can't deploy updates to my service with firebase deploy --only hosting.

I tried to use: firebase login --reauth, remove .firebaserc, but with no success. The error message is always the same:

```
Firebase CLI Login Failed
The Firebase CLI login request was rejected or an error occurred. Please run a firebase login again or contact support if you continue to have difficulty logging in.
```

I thought that it's related to antivirus, because today I installed Bitdefender, and after that, I installed eset trial version. But I'm not sure it can be a problem, because I tried to stop eset - no success. Any idea?

Comment: The error message is suggesting that you contact Firebase support: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Just a guess, but ESAT my be trying to intercept SSL/TLS connections and the Firebase CLI may be using certificate pinning (so it can detect intercepted connections). You might try [disabling SSL filtering](https://support.eset.com/en/kb3126-disable-ssl-filtering-in-eset-windows-products) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Doug, Yes I know, but last time when I contacted with support one issue takes 2 weeks. But ok, I sent a message to firebase support.
- 9072997, thx I will try!

Comment: And this is why I ask the Internet... It was a problem with intercepting SSL/TLS :) Problem resolved :) Thx @9072997!